# How nested loop works

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming, i just don't get how the nested loop like this works:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for i in range(2, n):
        print(n, i)
```

And the result:

```
3 2
4 2
4 3
5 2
5 3
5 4
6 2
6 3
6 4
6 5
7 2
7 3
7 4
7 5
7 6
8 2
8 3
8 4
8 5
8 6
8 7
9 2
9 3
9 4
9 5
9 6
9 7
9 8
```

Why does the first for loop start from 3 instead of 2 ?

Comment: Because the first time through your inner loop you get `range(2, 2)`, which doesn’t produce anything

Answer (score 1):

The first nested loop is effectively `range(2, 2)`. The `start` and `stop` are equal, thus resulting in an empty sequence. As such, it does not go into the second loop and then starts outputting results for `range(2, 3)`